# How can I see source code(include comments) within dependencies in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij has already downloaded source jar file in maven locally repository, but I can not see any comments in source code.

I have checked project structure of Intellij setting, screenshot as below. Could anyone help take a look?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you use a own repository it possible that it tries to download the sources from there but as you can see on the second screen on the right there is no sources jar in the repository.

Comment: @CodeMatrix the sources jar has existed in maven local repository, Intellij shouldn't have to download it again.

Comment: it caused by I didn't realize the difference between a `jar` and a `source-jar`. after `mvn dependency:sources` I can see now. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `mvn dependency:sources`. It will download source and javadoc.

Comment: :( it didn't download source for a particular source I was interested in though